# Ruby instance variable always nil outside `def initialize`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I have a controller method that passes an instance variable `@show_column` to a grid class. The problem is that although the value of the instance variable is available in `def initialize` of the grid class, it is `nil` outside `def initialize`:

The controller method:

```
  def index
    @show_column = (current_user && current_user.admin?)
    @grid = UsersGrid.new(params[:users_grid], @show_column) do |scope|
      scope.where(admin: false).page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
    end
    @grid.assets
  end
```

The grid class:

```
class UsersGrid
  include Datagrid
  attr_reader :show_column

  def initialize(*params, show_column)
    super *params
    @show_column = show_column
  end

  scope do
    User.order("users.created_at desc")
  end

  column(:abc, :header => "abc?", :html => true, :if => proc {@show_column == true}) do |user|
    image_tag("abc.png", title: "abc") if user.abc
  end
end
```

The problem is at the end with: `proc {@show_column == true}`. This doesn't work because `@show_column` is always `nil`. I've used a debugger to try to find some additional information. I shows that `@show_column` is set correctly in the controller; its value is `true` as it should be given the user I logged in with. Also, *inside* `def initialize` its value is `true`. However, *outside* `def initialize` in the grid class, its value is `nil`. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Change `:if => proc {@show_column == true})` line in your `UsersGrid` class to this: `:if => proc {show_column == true})` and then try

Comment: Then it produces the error `undefined local variable or method 'show_column' for UsersGrid:Class`.

Comment: Try attr_accessor instead of attr_reader

Comment: @TriveniBadgujar you really think adding a setter could change the outcome?

Comment: Now we see a progress here, don't we? It seems `@show_column` is expected to be a class variable not instance variable. Could you explain from where you're writing such a code? `UsersGrid` class looks like a Ruby class with no active record... is it coming from `Datagrid ` module?

Comment: Yes, it is coming from `Datagrid` module: app/grids/users_grid.rb. `Attr_accessor` made no difference; same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/wiki/Columns#if-and-unless-options-version--110), replace:

```
:if => proc {@show_column == true})
```

with:

```
:if => proc { |grid| grid.show_column == true})
```

or:

```
:if => :show_column
```

Comment: Yes, `:if => proc { |grid| grid.show_column == true}` worked!

Answer (score 0):

Inside a class declaration, `self` is the class itself, not an instance of the class. So, `@show_column` is an instance variable of `UsersGrid`, not an instance variable of an instance of `UsersGrid`.

Comment: While this answers the implicit question (why is it like this), it doesn't deal with the explicit one (how do I overcome this). OP could use something more than a hint, I think. :)

Comment: well it was in a proc, and unless you look at the code you cant be sure of its binding.

Comment: @apneadiving: You mean it could be `instance_eval`'d? True, but the error message the OP posted in the comments clearly talks about `UsersGrid`'s singleton class, so it's clear that `self` is `UsersGrid`.

Comment: true, but I guess you know you wrote a nice comment though not an answer :)